# Yii2 stripping ending slash in Url::to() route when using params

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using `Yii2` and have been using the [Url::to](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail) method without any issue. Now I just tried it with params for the first time and it strips the ending slash from my route.

So normally, say I would do this:

```
Url::to('/my/route/', true);
// http://www.example.com/my/route/
```

But if I want to pass params, such as:

```
Url::to('['/my/route/', 'id' => 123, 'name' => 'larry']', true);
// http://www.example.com/my/route?id=123&name=larry
```

Is there any way to stop it doing this, if not, do I have any other options to get what I want?

My `UrlManager` rule:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'pattern' => 'foo/<name:[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+>.<some_id:\d+>',
        'route' => 'foo/index',
        'suffix' => '/',
    ],
    //.........
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You can achieve that by adding `suffix` to corresponding url rule containing that route:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'pattern' => 'my/route',
                'route' => 'my/route',
                'suffix' => '/',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

**2)** Globally it's available through `urlManager` property with the same name `suffix`.

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'suffix' => '/',
    ],
],
```

**3)** Alternative way of setting through component:

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->suffix = '/';
```

This one works for specific routes too, just add this line before calling `Url::to()`;

Comment: The strange thing is I already have this route setup in `UrlManager` with the suffix `/`, so not sure why it wasn't working. However, doing `Yii::$app->urlManager->suffix = '/';` before the call to it worked. :)

Comment: Show the url rule so we can see what's wrong with it. I think you simply called it wrong.

Comment: Try this: `Url::to(['foo/index', 'name' => 'name', 'some_id' => 1, 'another_param' => 1], true)`.

Comment: So basically *leave off* the ending slash in the call to `Url::to()` ?

Comment: Slashes will be removed in initial stage of processing here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlManager.php#L306. You made error somewhere else. So it works now even with url rule settings?

Comment: Nope, only works still if I call `Yii::$app->urlManager->suffix = '/';`before calling the `Url::to()` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69409/discussion-between-arogachev-and-brett).